# WakeLock acquire and Release logs

Tags: android, wakelock

I want to write an appliaction/tool/utility/script etc. to monitor(log them somewhere/file/sdcard etc) the lock and release of all wake locks on my android device(JB). This utility/script etc should be able to log who acquired that wakelock and released a wakelock. This utility/script should monitor all wakelock requests(by apps/kernel/android OS itself I mean ALL). 
I have access to entire source code for the device and have su access.
Is there any way I can capture all the wakelock acquire+release logs for the entire device(all  apps/3rd party apps/android OS/kernel etc.)?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOveflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have formatted it and now it looks more like a question. Is that okay?